# ¿Cómo fusionar dos filas con pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Actualmente tengo un dataFrame que le leo de un fichero excel.

Este dataframe me saca los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
Precio 5 7 9 10
Valor1 2 3    9
Valor2     5
```

El resultado que quiero obtener en otro dataframe o en el mismo es el siguiente:

```
Precio 5 7 9 10
Valor  2 3 5 9
```

Es decir, fusionar ambas filas "valor1" y "valor2", siempre que haya un dato en "valor1" no lo habrá en "valor2" y viceversa por lo que sería simplemente juntarlos.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto con pandas?

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios publiquen sus preguntas junto con lo que han intentado, de esa forma se demuestra que has hecho un esfuerzo por resolver tu pregunta/problema, de lo contrario probablemente la pregunta termine cerrada y/o votada negativamente. Lectura recomendada: [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Pues tendrías que iterar por las tuplas del

> dataframe

y sobrescribir  los valores de la columna valor1 cuando tengas un dato en valor2.Luego eliminas la columna valor2 de la tabla.

Algo así:

```
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
'value1': [1, 2,None , 5],'value2': [None, None, 3,None ]})

print(df1)
for l in df1.itertuples():
      if df1.at[l.Index,'value2']>0: 
        df1.at[l.Index,'value1']=df1.at[l.Index,'value2']
        print(l.value2)
      else:
         print(l.value1)
df1.pop('value2')
print(df1)
```

1. Output:

```
      lkey  value1  value2
    0  foo     1.0     NaN
    1  bar     2.0     NaN
    2  baz     NaN     3.0
    3  foo     5.0     NaN
    1.0
    2.0
    3.0
    5.0
      lkey  value1
    0  foo     1.0
    1  bar     2.0
    2  baz     3.0
    3  foo     5.0
```

Una forma compacta y funcional de hacer lo mismo:

```
df1.value1=[float(row) for row in map(lambda x,y:np.where(pandas.isna(x),y,x),df1.value1,df1.value2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes hacerlo muy fácilmente con [`pandas.DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['Precio', 'Valor1', 'Valor2'],
                   1: [5, 2, np.nan],
                   2: [7, 3, np.nan],
                   3: [9, np.nan, 5],
                   4: [10, 9, np.nan]})
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)

# Dataframe original
print(df)

# Combinar las filas deseadas
df.loc['Valor1'] = df.loc['Valor1'].combine_first(df.loc['Valor2'])

# Eliminar la fila "Valor2"
df.drop('Valor2', inplace = True)

# Dataframe con filas combinadas
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
          1    2    3     4
0                          
Precio  5.0  7.0  9.0  10.0
Valor1  2.0  3.0  NaN   9.0
Valor2  NaN  NaN  5.0   NaN

          1    2    3     4
0                          
Precio  5.0  7.0  9.0  10.0
Valor1  2.0  3.0  5.0   9.0
```